# Retornar resultado javascript com controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, mvc

É possível dentro de um Controller, retornar uma ação javascript e proceder com o script do controller ?

Exemplo:

**Chamada para pagina de Login:**

```
<li><a href="javascript:" link="{{ route('login') }}" class="popup">logar</a></li>

$('.popup').click(function(ev){
    var URL = $(this).attr("link");

    window.open(URL,'janela', scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no');
});
```

**Controller**

```php
class testeController extends BaseController {

public function teste($process = null)
{
    if ($process) {
        return function();
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.close()</script>';

    if(Auth::check()){
        $role = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->roles()->first();
        return Redirect::to($role->name)->with('success', 'Logado com sucesso');
    }else{
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('warning', 'Não foi possível autenticá-lo, tente novamente mais tarde ou nos contate');
    }
...
```

porem o echo do javascript não funciona dentro do controller, somente se eu der um **return**, e se eu der um **return** o resto da função do controller não é executado.

Qual o melhor procedimento nesse caso ?

**Tentativa1:**

```
class testeController extends BaseController {

public function teste($process = null)
{
    if ($process) {
        return function();
    }

    Functions::jsController('close');

    if(Auth::check()){
        $role = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->roles()->first();
        return Redirect::to($role->name)->with('success', 'Logado com sucesso');
    }else{
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('warning', 'Não foi possível autenticá-lo, tente novamente mais tarde ou nos contate');
    }
...

public static function jsController($acao){
    if($acao == 'close'){
        return '<script type="text/javascript">window.close()</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: O melhor jeito de fazer isso é com Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível rodar o JavaScript de dentro do Controller do Laravel.

Nesse caso específico o melhor procedimento parece ser simplesmente incluir o código JavaScript `window.close()` no callback da sua chamada Ajax.

---

Tudo indica que você tem uma janela popup para fazer o login. Você quer que a janela popup feche e que o navegador seja redirecionado a um endereço específico.

O lado do *back-end* deve restringir-se a apenas verificar as credenciais, e retornar se houve **sucesso** ou **erro**.

- Se houve sucesso, deve também ativar o *cookie* de autenticação e informar o URL a ser redirecionado. Você pode usar `setcookie` e retornar um JSON mais ou menos assim: `{ "sucesso": true, "url": "http://exemplo.com/dashboard" }`
- Se houve erro, deve de preferência também indicar qual foi o erro, retornando um JSON mais ou menos assim: `{ "sucesso": false, "erro": "Senha incorreta." }`

Com esse retorno do Controller, o seu JavaScript *client-side* é que deve fechar a janela e redirecionar, ou mostrar a mensagem de erro.

**Nota**: essa é apenas uma abordagem possível dentre várias. (E eu estou assumindo que você tem uma janela popup aberta a partir de outra página.)

---

Apenas acrescentando mais informação: usando o jQuery no lado do cliente, existe a prática função `$.getScript(url);` que faz uma chamada Ajax à "url" e automaticamente executa o código JavaScript retornado. Assim, você pode retornar diretamente código JavaScript a ser executado:

```
class testeController {

    public function teste()
    {
        return 'window.close();'
    }

}
```

Esse conhecimento é útil, mas não creio que se aplique no seu caso.

Comment: muito boa sua explicação. Vou fazer os testes e ja retorno.

Comment: Bruni, sua terceira opcao me deu uma ideia boa, mas que tambem nao foi valida. Ainda nao consegui encontrar uma solucao. -- Topico atualizado

Comment: @tiaguinhow: A solução não é por aí. Você nunca vai conseguir redirecionar a janela que abriu o popup a partir do controller. Você não pode retornar uma coisa e depois rodar o `Redirect::to` numa única requisição.

Comment: Bruni, ainda nao consegui. Teria como dar uma incrementada no exemplo por favor ?